# parse.com parseobject.has("key"); in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Sorry, Objective-C noob here.

in java doing this is very simple. The code is just...

```
if(ParseObject.has("value"){
   //dosomething
 }
```

In objective-c there doesn't seem to be an equivilant to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values out of the `PFObject`, you can use either the `objectForKey:` method or the `[]` subscripting operator.

If there is no object for a given key, you will get **nil**.